# How to rescue item from list within an another list

Tags: android

I have a list, and inside I had a reference to an another list.

I use method to rescue the emailaddress, with getter but no possible, value are always null.

about this class :

```
public class MeetingUser {


    private String placeOfMeeting;
    private String objectOfMeeting;
    private List<User> usersList;//////////////////////Here
    private String hourMeeting;
    private String minuteMeeting;
    private String dateMeeting;
    private String monthMeeting;
    private String yearMeeting;



    public MeetingUser(String placeOfMeeting, String objectOfMeeting, List<User> usersList, String hourMeeting, String minuteMeeting, String dateMeeting, String monthMeeting, String yearMeeting) {
        this.placeOfMeeting = placeOfMeeting;
        this.objectOfMeeting = objectOfMeeting;
        this.usersList = usersList;
        this.hourMeeting = hourMeeting;
        this.minuteMeeting = minuteMeeting;
        this.dateMeeting = dateMeeting;
        this.monthMeeting = monthMeeting;
        this.yearMeeting = yearMeeting;

    }


    public MeetingUser() {
    }

    public String getPlaceOfMeeting() {
        return placeOfMeeting;
    }

    public void setPlaceOfMeeting(String placeOfMeeting) {
        this.placeOfMeeting = placeOfMeeting;
    }

    public String getObjectOfMeeting() {
        return objectOfMeeting;
    }

    public void setObjectOfMeeting(String objectOfMeeting) {
        this.objectOfMeeting = objectOfMeeting;
    }

    public List<User> getUsersList() {
        return usersList;
    }

    public void setUsersList(List<User> usersList) {
        this.usersList = usersList;
    }

    public String getHourMeeting() {
        return hourMeeting;
    }

    public void setHourMeeting(String hourMeeting) {
        this.hourMeeting = hourMeeting;
    }

    public String getMinuteMeeting() {
        return minuteMeeting;
    }

    public void setMinuteMeeting(String minuteMeeting) {
        this.minuteMeeting = minuteMeeting;
    }

    public String getDateMeeting() {
        return dateMeeting;
    }

    public void setDateMeeting(String dateMeeting) {
        this.dateMeeting = dateMeeting;
    }

    public String getMonthMeeting() {
        return monthMeeting;
    }

    public void setMonthMeeting(String monthMeeting) {
        this.monthMeeting = monthMeeting;
    }

    public String getYearMeeting() {
        return yearMeeting;
    }

    public void setYearMeeting(String yearMeeting) {
        this.yearMeeting = yearMeeting;
    }
}
```

I am trying to find user in this class :

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailAddress;


    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String emailAddress) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}

I am using method as this :

    public List<User> getUsers(String nom) {

        List<User> liste = new ArrayList<>();

        String emailSearch = "essai@essai.com";

        for(User user : userList) {
            if ( user.getLastName().equals(nom)) {//nom

                liste.contains(user);//.add(user);

            }emailSearch = user.getEmailAddress();

        } Log.d("TEST","*****************************method getUsers :                        "+emailSearch);

        return liste;

    }
```

And in my Array, I am trying to find like this :

```
    meetingUserList.add(new MeetingUser("Salle Ricocarpe","point sur avance batiment", getUsers("paulopaul"),"10","30","25","12","2020"));
```

It is in method getUSers, I search to have the email of "paulopaul".

thanks a lot for help

I have always a null result.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a user with `lastname` "paulopaul" in `userList`?

I think the logic inside your `getUsers` function is flawed. What you are doing basically is:

1. Iterating over a list of users, `userList`
2. For each user in the list check if the `lastname` equals the parameter passed, `nom`
3. If it is equal you are checking if it is already in `liste`
4. Then you are getting the users email

You are never adding elements to `liste`. If your intent is to add all users who have a `lastname` equal to `nom`, then you should use `liste.add(user);` instead of `liste.contains(user);`. When you do `liste.contains(user);` you are checking if that user is in the list, but it won't be since you are never adding any user.

Another problem is that if there are multiple users with lastname `nom`, `emailSearch = user.getEmailAddress();` will only get the email address from the last one before you use it in the Log statement. I assume that was only for debugging, but I'm not sure.

There could also be a problem with `userList` being empty or null, since I don't know where you are getting it from. You could easily check if it has users with `userList.isEmpty()` which will return `true` if it is indeed empty. To check if it's null use `if(userList == null)`.

If you are getting an error please post it here, as it will most likely tell what the problem is.